# SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() intermittently returns 0

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have searched many similar questions though i can't find any that **intermittently** returns 0

**** EDIT *****

I have since tried testing with a new table with only two columns, reduces the issue to around 1 in 50 times returning zero.

I have also just now been able to test on a paid hosting server and i could not replicate my issue

I assume the issue my be specific to that web host.

**Issue:**

When trying to retrieve the last inserted ID on a per connection basis, roughly 4 times out of ten i get a 0 returned to me.

Localhost, everything works fine without issue. The issue only arises when my website is hosted on a server.

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() intermittently returns 0

$PDOconnection->lastInsertId(); Always returns correct ID
```

I need to reliably get last inserted ID on a per connection basis as it's essential to the checkout process of my website when creating a purchase order in the database.

**Notes:**

- The ID is auto-incremented
- The sql insert always works fine and the database shows a new entry.
- Switching PHP version does not resolve the issue
- Web host i'm using is a free hosting service i'm using for live
  testing purposes
- Page load time is always similar (500 - 750ms for the code below)

I stripped the entire code down(as below) to test in simplicity. Issue still remains

I can't seem to workout where my issue lies.

```
include_once "php/config.php";

$cookie_id = 0;

// Time of checkout
$time = gmdate("d/m/Y h:i:s");

// Create new purchase order
$sql_insert = "INSERT INTO user_purchases (cart_id, timestamp) VALUES (:cookie_id, :time)";

$stmt_insert = $PDOconnection->prepare($sql_insert);
$stmt_insert->bindParam(':cookie_id', $cookie_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt_insert->bindParam(':time', $time, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt_insert->execute();

$checkout_id_0 = $PDOconnection->lastInsertId();

// Get the primary key id of the last inserted item on per-connection basis
$sql_last_id = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()";
$stmt_last_id = $PDOconnection->prepare($sql_last_id);
$stmt_last_id->execute();
$r_last_id = $stmt_last_id->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$checkout_id_1 = $r_last_id['LAST_INSERT_ID()'];

echo $checkout_id_0 . " " . $checkout_id_1;  // I echoed out to observe results
```

Real example of results for 10 queries in a row (simply by just refreshing the page). I echoed the results out side by side.

```
checkout_id_0      $checkout_id_1  <---SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()

      16                16
      17                17
      18                0        // Returned 0
      19                19
      20                0        // Returned 0
      21                0        // Returned 0
      22                22
      23                23
      24                23       // Returned previous ID (happens 1/30 tries)
      25                25
```

Connection config:

```
$PDOconnection = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8", $sql_username, $sql_password);

// Set PDO error mode to exception
$PDOconnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

// Set PDO Attribute to force native prepared statements
$PDOconnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
```

Comment: Any reason why you can't use the value returned from `lastInsertId`? Are you using `mysqlnd`? (.. which [support connection pooling, where a new, different connection might be used for each query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlnd-ms.pooling.php)).

Comment: Using mysqlnd. I was under the impression SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() would be more reliable in an e-comm checkout scenario being that you would only ever get the ID returned for that specific client?

Comment: @MatsLindh I have since tried testing with a new table with only two columns and it has reduced the issue to around 1 in 50 times returning zero. I have also just now been able to test on a paid hosting server and i could not replicate my issue, I assume the issue my be specific to that web host.

Comment: @user3796133 *"I was under the impression... that specific client."*  I suspect you are working from an incorrect definition of "client."  What do you mean, when you say *client*?

Comment: Yes, sorry i meant a customer purchasing something from the website.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried activating persistent connections? See [Connections and Connection management](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php) and [Persistent Database Connections](http://php.net/manual/en/features.persistent-connections.php). Maybe that remote server has too short MySQL settings - [`wait_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout) and [`interactive_timeout`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_interactive_timeout)...

> Persistent connections are not closed at the end of the script, but
>   are cached and re-used when another script requests a connection using
>   the same credentials. The persistent connection cache allows you to
>   avoid the overhead of establishing a new connection every time a
>   script needs to talk to a database, resulting in a faster web
>   application.

Also note:

> If you wish to use persistent connections, you must set
>   PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT in the array of driver options passed to the PDO
>   constructor. If setting this attribute with PDO::setAttribute() after
>   instantiation of the object, the driver will not use persistent
>   connections.

So:

```
$PDOconnection = new PDO(
    "mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname;charset=utf8"
    , $sql_username
    , $sql_password
    , array(
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true,
    )
);
```